# Simple validation for <td contenteditable="true"> element.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I have a table which consists of data from MYSQL, and whenever I make changes in an element in table, my database will be updated by ajax.
This is my javascript code to send the data in editable row.

```
        function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {    
        $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF url(images/loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");
        $("#tabs-1").load(location.href + " #tabs-1");
            $.ajax({
                url: "saveedit.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
                success: function(data){
                    $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
                }
           });              
    }
```

After the function above, saveedit.php will deal with updating the database and it's functional.

Then, this is my table in html and these table elements are editable.

```
        <?php
            $result = FUNCTION_TO_RETRIEVE_DATA_FROM_DB;
            foreach($result as $k=>$v){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $k+1; ?></td>
            <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this, 'memberID', '<?php echo $result[$k]["memberID"]; ?>')"><?php echo $result[$k]["memberID"]; ?></td>

            <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this, 'surname', '<?php echo $result[$k]["memberID"]; ?>')"><?php echo $result[$k]["surname"]; ?></td>

            <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this, 'forename', '<?php echo $result[$k]["memberID"]; ?>')"><?php echo $result[$k]["forename"]; ?></td>

            <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this, 'address', '<?php echo $result[$k]["memberID"]; ?>')"><?php echo $result[$k]["address"]; ?></td>

            <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this, 'gradeID', '<?php echo $result[$k]["memberID"]; ?>')"><?php echo $result[$k]["gradeID"]; ?></td>                                
        </tr>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
```

This code is working, but the question I would like to ask is, how can I validate the data entered by the user into this  element? For example, what if I would like to check the initial column, memberID, cannot be longer than 6 characters, or if it is required or not. What I am trying to do is to validate entered data before sending it using AJAX but now but I have no idea how validation can be done in the table element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before calling ajax validate your column by putting condition before it.

```
` function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {  
    $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF url(images/loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");
        $("#tabs-1").load(location.href + " #tabs-1");
           if(column == "memberID"){
               if(editableObj.innerHTML.length > 6 ) { 
                      alert("cannot be longer than 6 characters");
                      return false;
                }else{
                      $.ajax({
                        url: "saveedit.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
                        success: function(data){
                        $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
                       }
                    }); 
                   }
                 }             
    }`
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! Your code was specific enough for me to understand how I can validate them.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling the `saveToDatabase()` function put the desired validation on the entered  value like:

```
var newVal = editableObj.innerHTML;
// Your validation on newVal, if validation successful call the saveToDatabase() function
// Otherwise show an error message and do nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the passing parameter and only process ajax when your condition is satisfied.

```
function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {   
//If(editableObj.length > 6) // Case of string Check your other condition.
if(editableObj.toString().length > 6) // in case it is not string.
{
alert(Condition fail);
}
else
{
 // Your ajax call -------
}

}
```

Or :

Check your passing data before calling `saveToDatabase` function.

Comment: `editableObj` is string ?? if it is string its give you a length.

Comment: editableObj is an object, and your new update worked too! editableObj.innerHTML.length worked same. Thank you for your help!